# Convergence of random variable Poisson distribution

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let $X_1,...,X_n \sim \mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda_n)$ where $\lambda_n=1/n$ and let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I have to show that $Y_n=nX_n$ converges to $0$ in probability. My approach: (using Markov's inequality)

Note that $Y_n$ is a non-negative random variable since $n\geq 1$ and $X_n$ is also non-negative (Poisson). Therefore by Markov's inequality it holds that:

$$P(Y_n >t) \leq \frac{E(Y_n)}{t} = \frac{E(nX_n)}{t}=\frac{nE(X_n)}{t} = \frac{n\lambda_n}{t} = \frac{1}{t},$$

for all $t\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$. However for $n \rightarrow \infty$ we do not see that $P(Y_n > t)\rightarrow 0$ so what is wrong with this approach?

Comment: The limit of the t-statistic becomes the mean and the generating moment of the expectation value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just compute directly. For any $\epsilon>0$,
$$
P(|Y_n|>\epsilon)
=P(nX_n>\epsilon)
=P(X_n>\epsilon/n)
\le P(X_n> 0)=1-e^{-1/n}\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow 0.
$$
There is nothing much to say about what is wrong with your approach. It was a good idea, you executed it well, but it turned out not to be useful. That is just how it goes sometimes in math!

Comment: Nice answer! One question, convergence in probability is only well-defined if it holds for all $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ so you could write: $P(nX_n > \epsilon) = P(X_n >\epsilon/n) \leq P(X_n >0) \rightarrow 0$

Comment: @Dani Good point, fixed.